# User Control as starting Page of Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question. 
In my web application xxx.ascx is User control. Is it possible to set xxx.ascx as the starting page of a project?

Comment: sashidhar your question is unclear

Comment: I mean suppose a user control can be a starting page of project is it possible?

Comment: ok ok i understand user control is a control it can't be a staring page of the project am i right?

Comment: ya defenitely you cant..

Comment: You can set the default index in IIS or your web.config file, but it has to be a page, not a user control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sashidhar ASPX is a page and ASCX is a usercontrol. A page can contain usercontrols...

you can always replace a default.aspx page with your xxxx.aspx page which can contain your user control xxx.ascx

aspx and ascx are different

Comment: Thank you Mr. Pandiya Chendur I understand aspx is a page ascx id control. a user control can't be a starting page but it can place in a page which is default.aspx it is possible am i right?

Comment: @Surya sasidhar: aspx is a page ascx is a user control. a user control can't be a starting page but it can be placed in any page, including the default page that can be or not the default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A user control (.ascx) can not be referenced directly, without a container page (.aspx)
So, the answer is no.

But, of course, you can make a small page that only have this control.

Comment: Ya Mr. Edrado Molteni I understand a user control can't be a starting page. why because it is not a .aspx

Answer (score 0):

create a new aspx file, set that file as the starting page for your project, and then place your user control on that page.